Date of First and Last Days of Current and Last Weeks
How to get the Date of First & Last days of Current Week and Last Week. Considering the Week start with Saturday and ends with Friday.
Here is my unsuccessful trial :
//Last Week
DateTime _startLw = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-(7 + ((int)DateTime.Today.Date.DayOfWeek - 1 == -1 ? 6 : (int)DateTime.Today.Date.DayOfWeek - 1)));
DateTime _endLw = _startLw.AddDays(7);
    
//This Week    
DateTime _startTw = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek); 
DateTime  _endTw = _startTw.AddDays(7);

However i don't know how to make the week start with saturday and ends with Friday.

what did you try? We're not here to do your job, which is thinking, trying out, thinking again. Please provide what you've tried and where you're stuck.

One of potential error in your code is DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek returns a value where Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6. When you subtract 1 from it, it will lead to incorrect indices when you try to normalize for Saturday.

If you calculate the start of the current week. You can use that as a base for all the other dates.
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime currentWeekStart = GetWeekStart(today);
DateTime currentWeekEnd = currentWeekStart.AddDays(6);
DateTime lastWeekEnd = currentWeekStart.AddDays(-1);
DateTime lastWeekStart = lastWeekEnd.AddDays(-6);

static DateTime GetWeekStart(DateTime date)
{
    int diff = (date.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Saturday + 7) % 7;
    return date.AddDays(-diff);
}


Works Perfectly, Regards

In general case (note, that start of week is culture dependent; say, it is Sunday in English culture and Monday in German):
public static class DateTimeextensions {
  public static DateTime WeekStart(this DateTime value, CultureInfo? culture = default) {
    culture ??= CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    var delta = (value.DayOfWeek - culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

    return value.Date.AddDays(-delta);
  }
}

Usage
DateTime currentWeekStart = DateTime.Today.WeekStart();

